# Big-O notation in division

Tags: calculus

Let $r(x)=\frac{p(x)}{q(x)}$. Expending $p$ and $q$ around 0 gives
$$
\frac{p_0+p'_0x+\mathcal{O}(x^2)}{q_0+q'_0x+\mathcal{O}(x^2)}.
$$
Now the claim is that the above expression is equal to
$$
\frac{p_0+p'_0x}{q_0+q'_0x}+\mathcal{O}(x^2).
$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are comfortable with the similar calculation for multiplication, you really one need to show that
$$\frac{1}{q_0+q'_0x+\mathcal{O}(x^2)}=\frac{1}{q_0+q'_0x}+\mathcal{O}(x^2).$$
To see this, consider
$$\frac{1}{q_0+q'_0x+\mathcal{O}(x^2)}-\frac{1}{q_0+q'_0x}=\frac{-\mathcal{O}(x^2)}{\big(q_0+q'_0x+\mathcal{O}(x^2)\big)\big(q_0+q'_0x\big)}.$$
You'd better have $q_0\ne0$ for this to work, of course.

Answer (score 0):

Try to evaluating the difference:
$\displaystyle \frac{p_0+p'_0x+\mathcal{O}(x^2)}{q_0+q'_0x+\mathcal{O}(x^2)}-\frac{p_0+p'_0x}{q_0+q'_0x}$
and recall that $p\mathcal{O}(x^2)=\mathcal{O}(x^2)$ and $x\mathcal{O}(x^2)=\mathcal{O}(x^2)$.

Comment: For anybody else looking at this $x\mathcal{O}(x^2) = \mathcal{O}(x^3)$